# How to enable the trigger event by the element or by its child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hammer.js

I am using [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) to enable touch gesutre onto a `ul`.

The `ul` has its `li` elements and each `li` has an `img`. The `ul` functions ok when directly dragged on the `ul` itself. But if I try to drag by its child element ( `li` or `img`), nothing happens. How can I make it work to enable dragging/touch even when clicked within its child element?

demo at: [codepen](http://codepen.io/aamus/pen/EPVQJr).

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.natureasia.com/common/img/splash/thailand.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/19500000/Wow-nature-19546776-600-400.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i499.photobucket.com/albums/rr359/jatruong/nature-wallpaper-11.png">
    </li>
    <span class="clear-both"></span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
var element = $('ul');

element.hammer().on('pan', function(event) {
  console.log('pan-x: ' + event.gesture.deltaX + 'px');
  element.css('left', event.gesture.deltaX);
});

element.hammer().on('panend', function(event) {
  element.css('left', '0px');
});
```

Comment: quick solution: var element = $('ul, ul li, ul li img');

Comment: @MoonYard hahaha! Thanks. I will try it.